# Why is my HTML document only using a few of the CSS-sheets I ask it to use?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am creating a responsive webpage with 3 CSS-sheets, one for mobile, one for tablets and one for desktops.

But if I put any kind of code in my tablet css-sheet, the webpage seems to ignore it. I have been trying valiantly to make my document use 100% width on main articles on smaller screens (by pushing down the sidebars that way) and then change it to 79% on bigger screens but I am getting no reaction what-so-ever from my tablet-CSS, even though my PC-sheet changes to width: 79% with no problem and the main CSS (mobile first design!) whips up the 100% width without trouble.

Could someone please take a look and see if they can figure out why this is happening? I am sure this must be caused by some silly little thing I have overlooked, but I just cant seem to find out how to fix it. Please help?
[Image of my sheets so you can see that they are named correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etuKQ.jpg)

**From index:**

```
   [<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<!--Henvisning til eksterne sheets osv-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1051px)" href="styletablet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1052px)" href="stylepc.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>][1]
```

**My main CSS (mobile)** Works fine

```
.content { width: 100%; float: left;}
```

**My tablet style sheet**, utterly ignored. the BG color works fine, but the width does not

```
       .mainheader nav{ background-color: green;}
.content { width: 79%;
           float: left;}
```

**PC-stylesheet** works fine

```
body {font-size:100%;
      color: red;}

.content { width: 79%;
           float: left;}
```

Comment: are you sure it is not using a cached version of your css file?

Comment: `and(min-width: 641px)` is not valid. Put a space after `and`. You can validate your HTML to notice this immediately.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) to find out which style sheets and which media queries are currently active. Make sure they don’t override each other.

Comment: Thank you so much Xufox. All that trouble and struggle due to one missing "space". I am embarrassed I did not notice it or validate my document, but it was a valuable lesson and I am so exited about the dev tools, it makes things so much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest scrapping your three style sheets and only use the style.css

In your style.css do something like this:

```
/* Desktop Styles */

.example {
   height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width:1052px){
    /* Tablet Styles */

    .example {
       height: 50px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:641px){
    /* MobileStyles */

    .example {
       height: 25px;
    }
}
```